# how to use exclude with babel-loader in vue cli3?

Tags: vue.js, babeljs, vue-cli, vue-cli-3, babel-loader

I want to use exclude to ignore some dir to not compile, but in Vue Cli3, it not works. My option is:

```js
chainWebpack: config => {
  config.module
    .rule('js')
    .test(/\.jsx?$/)
    .use('babel-loader')
    .loader('babel-loader')
    .exclude
    .add(resolve('src/libs/iview'))  // this line not work
    .end();
  }
```

Error:

```
 TypeError: Cannot read property 'add' of undefined
```

Answer (score 1):

To exclude a file from Babel transpile, you can use the excludes option for the js babel-loader. An example is below.

Caveats:

1. Strings must be absolute paths (use path.resolve if needed)
2. Regexp works
3. Functions work

```js
// const path = require('path') // somewhere at the top of the file...
chainWebpack: config => {
  config.module
    .rule('js')
      .exclude
      .add(/path\/to\/folder\/.+\.ignore/) // Regexp: ignore anything inside of path/to/folder that has .ignore in the file extension
//    .add(path.resolve('./path/to/the/folder')) // example with a nix folder
//    .add('C:\\path\\to\\the\\folder\\') // absolute path, example with a Windows folder
    .end()
}
```

The command `vue inspect module.rules` will return:

```js
[...]
/* config.module.rule('js') */
  {
    test: /\.m?jsx?$/,
    exclude: [
      function () { /* omitted long function */ },
      'C:\\path\\to\\the\\folder\\'
    ],
    use: [
      /* config.module.rule('js').use('cache-loader') */
      {
        loader: 'cache-loader',
        options: {
          cacheDirectory: '[...]\\node_modules\\.cache\\babel-loader',
          cacheIdentifier: '2e75750d'
        }
      },
      /* config.module.rule('js').use('babel-loader') */
      {
        loader: 'babel-loader'
      }
    ]
  }
```

Answer (score -3):

Just remove this:

```
.use('babel-loader')
.loader('babel-loader')
```

and it works.